# Fading slideshow Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are tons of fading slideshows to copy and paste.. but I want to understand how it all works... So I have this working slideshow in JavaScript. How do I add a fade effect to it? Can it be done by adding the jquery fadeOut() method? 
Thanks in advance!

```
var counter = 0;

function slideShow() {
var pics = [6];

pics[0] = "bilder/1.jpg";
pics[1] = "bilder/2.jpg";
pics[2] = "bilder/3.jpg";
pics[3] = "bilder/4.jpg";
pics[4] = "bilder/5.jpg";
pics[5] = "bilder/6.jpg";

document.getElementById('bildspelsrc').src = pics[counter];

counter++;
if (counter % 6 == 0) counter = 0;
}

setInterval(slideShow,1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pics[] = {...//images in here}
var idx = 0;

function slide(){
 idx++;
 if(idx == pics.length)
   idx =0;

 $("#bildspelsrc").fadeOut(1000, function(){
    $("#bildspelsrc").attr("src", pics[idx]).fadeIn(1000);
 });
}
```

**UPDATED**
you will need a trigger, try to call this at page load

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(slide,1000);
});
```

this will loop through your images array and fade them out first, then fade in the new image

**UPDATE 2**
for animate just replace fade part with

```
$('#bildspelsrc').animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
        $(this).attr({'src': pics[idx]}).animate({opacity: 1});
    });
```

Comment: Ok, will give it a new try.. I'm thinking of doing .animate instead of fade... think it will look smoother :)

Comment: Sweet, will try that also!

Comment: animate doesn't cross-fade... hmm

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this won't work with your current method. $.fadeOut() fades the element, in your slideshow you are actually changing an attribute.  You can't fade one picture to another picture.  The proper way is to make all the slides their own DOM element and fade between those.  There are many examples of that on the internet.  But if you do want to stick to the way you are doing it you may fadeOut the element, change the src, then fadeIn the element.

```
    $('#bildspelsrc').fadeOut(250, function () { $(this)[0].src = pics[counter]; }).fadeIn(250);
```

Here is a link to a proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/dhQk/Y6Epm/

**EDIT**
Created a new version for you as a start of how most other sliders start out.  This is where it takes each slide and stores it in memory.  Then fades them in one at a time.  The code is heavily commented to help you out.

http://jsfiddle.net/dhQk/Y6Epm/4/

Comment: Worked like a charm, but it would be nice with a cross-fade. I guess that's a different story...

Comment: I went ahead and updated it for you to do a cross-fade.  Note the css required.